# How to up scale video resolution for Video Card

Tags: video, video-capture

I've a Black Magic Declink Mini Recorder Frame Grabber which supports minimum 720p as Video Input. But my camera has a VGA resolution which ostensibly will give output in 640*480 resolution. The card accepts both SDI/HDMI slots for Intput and Camera cable I have is currently having BNC Connector at it's end. Could someone suggest how can I use this Video Card to process VGA Video Output from my camera?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not (only) resolution.  640x480 resolution VGA is analog video, so you need an analog -> digital video converter.  This $200 [Analog -> SDI Mini Converter](http://www.markertek.com/product/bmd-convmas/blackmagic-convmaas2-analog-to-3g-hd-sdi-mini-converter?gclid=Cj0KEQiA_MK0BRDQsf_bsZS-_OIBEiQADPf--gCDqnzXY8iHS6E75lhDi66w9oMOeX44nQdK2M4zfWYaAile8P8HAQ) from Blackmagic Design will do what you need.

Then again, for not much more than $200, you can get a camera that speaks HDMI and gives you true 720p.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I believe the Mini Recorder will take the analog signal and give the digital output. However, I do wish to know if it's possible to provide the VGA video as input to some converter and get the 720p resolution which can be fed to the Video Card I have!?

Comment: I believe that if you feed 640x480 analog video into a Blackmagic miniconverter, you will get upscaled digital video out at 720p or 1080p, but not less than 720p.

Comment: While Michael Already mentioned a "professional" version, you can find this much cheaper as well, here is a generic converter box for 30$ http://www.amazon.com/Etekcity®-Composite-Converter-Upscaler-High-definition/dp/B00MNFWYBI